# Ext.net MessageBox not fired immediately in loop statements

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

To get the Confirmation from user, I am using the Confirmation Message Box i.e Ext.net MessageBox to Confirm the Decision of the User using the ButtonConfig, as like below.

```
private void checkThePolicies()
{
  .......

  foreach (int policyId in PoliciesDeleted)
                {
                    X.Msg.Confirm( "User Policy", "Do you want to Delete the Policy", new MessageBoxButtonsConfig
                    {
                        Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
                        {

                            Handler = "#{DirectMethods}.fnSaveTimeOffTypeInAllowance()",
                            Text = "Yes"
                        },
                        No = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
                        {
                            Text = "No"
                        }
                    }).Show();

........
}
```

But this message box is showing Only once for Entire loop at last when it's execution is leaving form that Method.

Why this happens? I want to execute the Handler for every Loop by confirming the Decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X.Msg.Confifm().Show();
```

just generates JavaScript to be executed when a browser gets a response from server.

It doesn't send a request to a browser immediately.

Comment: Ok Thank you, so is there any alternative way to invoke Messagebox in the middle of the function and handling the method as like Desktop applications in Ext.net

Comment: No, there is no such a way. You should ask a user first in one server method, then a user responds something on client and you can handle his answer in another server method. Though you might be interested in the SignalR functionality: http://www.ext.net/2013/03/19/signalr-with-ext-net/